# Change PlayServices alert text

Tags: android, dialog

I'm using this code to check if Play Services are availble

```
public static boolean checkPlayServices(Context context, boolean showDialog) {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (showDialog) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, (BaseActivity) context, GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE);

                dialog.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("FUApp", "This device is not supported.");
                //finish();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is it possible to change the Dialog text without having to create a new dialog?

The reason being I only want to show the error if they are trying to use a feature which requires Play Services, and the current text says `This app wont work...`, whereas I want it to say `This feature wont work...`

Comment: You just need to import library project to manipulate the text instead of using its jar file.I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**
 import `google-play-services_lib` to your workspace

( you can find it on following path: `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/`)

**Step 2:**
go to its `values` directory -> `strings.xml`
and change the text messages which you want to change.

**Step 3:** 
Now come back to your own application, add `google-play-services_lib` as library project to your application.

You're done !!

**EDIT :**

Instead of making changes in library's `strings.xml`, you can override desired string value in your application's `strings.xml`

i.e.:

```
<string name="common_google_play_services_enable_text" msgid="227660514972886228">This feature won\'t work unless you enable Google Play services.</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go now :). I'm currently using gradle rather than import the library, is importing it the only way to achieve this?

Comment: @TomHart: I'm not familiar with gradle.I wish I can learn it too.